# QEMU with KVM, issue with Windows recognizing the virtual environment

Tags: virtualization, qemu, kvm, gentoo, solidworks

I'm running Gentoo right now, I'm using QEMU with KVM support to run a Windows VM, I need to because they're forcing us to use a proprietary CAD software at university (sadly enough). They gave us a license for a year, however when I activate it, it clearly says the license can't be used in a virtual environment. This leads me to the conclusion that somehow the system recognizes it is being emulated and I know there's a way to avoid this, but I actually have no idea what to do. I've read someone had the same problem and apparently solved it, however his solution doesn't seem to work for me. I'll leave you the URL of the question on Stack. https://serverfault.com/questions/727347/solidworks-activation-license-mode-is-not-supported-in-this-virtual-environment

This command:

```
    qemu-system-x86_
64 -enable-kvm -hda windows.qcow2 -cpu host,kvm=off -smbios type=0,vendor=LENOVO,version=FBKTB4AUS,date=07/01/2015,release=1.180 -smbios type=1,manufacturer=LENOVO,product=30AH001GPB,version=ThinkStation P300,serial=S4M88119,uuid=cecf333d-6603-e511-97d5-6c0b843f98ba,sku=LENOVO_MT_30AH,family=P300 -m 8G
```

gives the output:

```
    qemu-system-x86_64: -smbios type=1,manufacturer=LENOVO,product=30AH001GPB,version=ThinkStation: drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists
```

I have no idea what to do, I also checked with ruby that the command I pasted from the post I've linked is actually ASCII, it is correct apparently.
I really need this to work, doesn't even work with a cracked license.
Thank you.

Comment: Update:
Apparently there was a syntax mistake I didn't notice,

    version=ThinkStation P300

must be read as a whole command, therefore 

    version="ThinkStation P300"

The problem is that now it still recognizes it's a virtual environment and I have no idea how this happens